How can I authorize a DialogFlow service account to invoke Google Apps Script web application?
I'm building a proof of concept with Google Vertex AI Agent Console.
I'm stuck trying to get my agent to invoke a tool deployed as a Google Apps Script web application (running as me and available --for now-- to anyone).
I can invoke the scripts with no problem from make.com, a stranger's web browser, and so on. But I get a 401 authorization error when I try to invoke from my agent.
In my tool description in the agent console, I provide valid OpenAPI YAML, and the following settings:

Authentication type:
Service agent token
OAuth
API Key
Bearer Token


Service agent auth type:ID tokenAccess token

I linked the Apps Script to the Agent project, and granted the dialog flow service account both Cloud Function Invoker and Cloud Runner Invoker roles.
I've decoded the Google-style token, which looks well-formed,  though I'm not sure how to interpret the "aud" value.
I'm stumped, and can't put in the time to become a Google IAM expert now.
Very grateful for any insight.
My "agent" invoked an "OpenAPI tool" and I expected to get back "hello world."  Instead I get a 401 error (even though the URL is presently public).
